# Error while inserting one string in another

Tags: python, string, string-comparison

I have a string `s= 'aaeekmnnry'` and another string `p = 'aka'`. I want to insert p at the 2nd index at s so that my output is `ans = 'aaakaeekmnrry'`. To achieve this, I wrote the following piece of code:

```
f = p[0]
i = 0
while i < len(s):
    if p[0] <= s[i]:
        i+=1
    else:
        break    
ans = ''.join(s[:i]) + ''.join(p) + ''.join(s[i:])
```

But my index `i` becomes length of the string and ouput is `'aaeekmnnryaka'`, I was expecting `i` to become 2. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems you have 2 different criteria, "2nd index" in the description, but you are doing a compare `if p[0] <= s[i]:` in the code as though you are trying to insert p at the first character greater than p[0]. So, which is it?

Comment: Actually, I want to place ```p``` at the index such that the first character of ```p``` just lexicographically greater than the inserting position of s. Can you help me?

Comment: Got it. BTW, I think that's `ans = 'aaakaeekmnnry'` (two n's one r)

Comment: FYI, `'a'` is less than or equal to all characters in `s`.

Comment: Oh, I got it, sorry. I have corrected the code

Comment: As mentioned by @Austin, `p[0]` is never lexicographically greater than any characters in `s`. Your desired result suggests that you want p where its LESS than the characters in s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting your conditions wrong. You should break out when you see the letter in `s` is lexicographically higher.

```
i = 0
while i < len(s):
    if p[0] < s[i]:
        break
    else:
        i += 1

ans = s[:i] + p + s[i:]
# aaakaeekmnnry
```

Comment: I think this is correct. Hopefully OP will clarify conditions and mark this the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are one character away from the correct answer! Your `<=` wants to be `>=` - you keep incrementing the position while the first character of your `p` string is **greater** than (or equal to) the character in `s` at the position which you are currently examining. Apart from that, your code is correct.